# No carga la clase .php llamada

Tags: php, jquery

Tengo 2 archivos :

load.html y colores.php

El archivo load.html es :

```html
<html>

<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var x;
        x=$(document);
        x.ready(inicio);
        
        function inicio(){
            var x;
            x=$("a");
            x.click(muestrame);
        }
        
        function muestrame(){
            var pagina=$(this).attr("href");
            var x=$("#hablame");
            x.load(pagina);
            return false;
        }
    </script>
    <style type="text/css">
        
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <a href="colores.php?color=verde">Hablame del verde</a>
    <a href="colores.php?color=rojo">Hablame del rojo</a>
    <a href="colores.php?color=azul">Hablame del azul</a>
    <div id="hablame"></div>
</body>
    
</html>
```

Y el archivo colores.php es :

```html
<?php
if($_GET['color'] == "verde"){
    echo "El color verde es muy relajante";
}
if($_GET['color'] == "rojo"){
    echo "El color rojo es muy pasional";
}

if($_GET['color'] == "azul"){
    echo "El color azul es muy templado";
}

?>
```

Cuando se carga la web load.html y doy clic en los hipervicunlos no funciona el código sql y no hace nada.

De antemano gracias por el apoyo brindado.

Slds
Luis

Comment: Te falta controlar los clicks. Por otro lado, no hay código SQL.

Comment: Hay algo muy básico que es preciso entender: `load.html` se ejecutará del lado del cliente (en este caso en el navegador), mientras que `colores.php` se ejecutará del lado del servidor. Tú no podrás en ningún caso mostrar en `load.html` lo que ocurre en el servidor tal y como lo estás haciendo ahora. Aquí, cuando la llamada es hecha, a lo sumo, se abre una página nueva que será `colores.php`... pero ya no tienes cargada a `load.html`. Entonces, ¿cómo puedo mostrar lo que ocurre en `colores.php` desde `load.html`? La respuesta es una sola: **enviando una petición vía Ajax**.

Answer (score -1):

Puedes comenzar comprobando que se llama correctamente al código PHP indicado:

```
<?php
echo "Entrando en el PHP colores.php";
echo "He recibido el color: " . $_GET['color'];

if($_GET['color'] == "verde"){
    echo "El color verde es muy relajante";
}
if($_GET['color'] == "rojo"){
    echo "El color rojo es muy pasional";
}

if($_GET['color'] == "azul"){
    echo "El color azul es muy templado";
}

?>
```

Si la ruta del PHP no te la coje directamente prueba a forzar la URL escribiendo en tu codigo HTML:

```
...
    <a href="./colores.php?color=verde">Hablame del verde</a>
    <a href="./colores.php?color=rojo">Hablame del rojo</a>
    <a href="./colores.php?color=azul">Hablame del azul</a>
...
```

---

Nota:
Tambien puedes usar **$_REQUEST**, que recoge tanto $_POST, $_GET y $_COOKIE

Comment: Hola Luis
Intente y al momento que llama al archivo php me lanza el siguiente mensaje:

echo "Entrando en el PHP colores.php";
echo "He recibido el color: " .$_GET['color'];

if($_GET['color'] == "verde"){
    echo "El color verde es muy relajante";
}
if($_GET['color'] == "rojo"){
    echo "El color rojo es muy pasional";
}

if($_GET['color'] == "azul"){
    echo "El color azul es muy templado";
}

?>

Por lo que me parece no está cogiendo el código PHP.

Comment: Parece que tu servidor no tiene instalado o configurado un intérprete de PHP.

Comment: Hola, tengo instalado el xamp con PHP/Apache/MySQL
=/